# how to force Bootstrap-5 to build a grid without stretching columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a very simple Bootstrap-grid, looking like this:
[image: (Bootstrap grid with default stretching)]

(here in red outlined spaces which should be ommited)

I want to build a grid which will be filled from-right-to-left, and without filling the whole parent container (so accordingly no columns should be stretched).

How can I do this?

that's source code of grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p class="mb-0  fw-bold">xx xx xxxx</p>
        <p class="text-secondary">Employee Range</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p class="mb-0  fw-bold ">xxxx</p>
        <p class="text-secondary">Rechtsform</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p class="mb-0  fw-bold" >xxx-xxx.xxx.x&nbsp;xxxx</p>
        <p class="text-secondary">xxx.-xx</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p class="mb-0  fw-bold" >xx-xxx.x.xxx.xxx-x</p>
        <p class="text-secondary">Handelsregister-Nummer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `col-auto` on all the column divs, it takes the width of the content (text in this case).
It may still occupy the whole container with the last col being stretched, in that case just remove the col classes, the div by default is large as its content (if it shouldn't for some css you have elsewhere, just add `width: auto`)
But I suggest you go with col-auto or you lose the bs builtin responsiveness.

For text align, if you meant that by filled from right to left, add class `text-right` to each column div instead.

Comment: You should reply to him not to me